# Ayuda con [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '2'. This may cause an update error

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

buenas me aparace este error al momento de cargar una tabla con los datos, me podrian ayudar?

esta es la tabla donde esta el error:

```
<v-data-table
        :loading="loading"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="contracts"
        loading-text="Cargando contratos..."
        no-data-text="No hay contratos cargados"
        :footer-props="{
          itemsPerPageText: 'Contratos por pagina',
          itemsPerPageAllText: 'Todos'
        }"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.current_fee="props">$ {{ props.item.current_fee }}</template>

        <template v-slot:item.actions="props">
          <contract-show v-bind:contract="props.item"></contract-show>
          <contract-edit v-bind:id="props.item.id" @contractUpdated="onContractUpdated"></contract-edit>
          <contract-delete v-bind:contract="props.item"></contract-delete>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

este es el controller desde el cual se realiza la consulta y devuelve los datos hacia la tabla, el controller realiza una busqueda a travez de 1 o mas campos y devuelve los registros cuyos valores concuerden con los datos ingresado, en el caso que sea un administrador devuelve todos los registros que desee buscar en caso contrario realiza la busqueda de la sucursal a la cual pertenece el usuario , el return del final es un transformador para asignarle nombres a las variables:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name       = $request->firstname;
        $lastname   = $request->lastname;
        $cellphone  = $request->cellphone;
        $domicile   = $request->domicile;
        $cdcontract = $request->cdcontract;
        $branch     = $request->branchname; 
        $branch1    = request()->user()->branch_id;

        if (request()->user()->hasRole('admin')) 
        {
            $contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                            ->join('branches', 'branches.id' , '=', 'contracts.branch_id')
                            ->when($name != null, function ($query) use ($name) {
                                $query->where('affiliates.first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%");
                            })
                            ->when($lastname != null, function ($query) use ($lastname) {
                                $query->where('affiliates.last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$lastname}%");
                            })
                            ->when($cellphone != null, function ($query) use ($cellphone) {
                                $query->where('contracts.cellphone', 'LIKE', "%{$cellphone}%");
                            })
                            ->when($domicile != null, function ($query) use ($domicile) {
                                $query->where('contracts.domicile', 'LIKE', "%{$domicile}%");
                            })
                            ->when($cdcontract != null, function ($query) use ($cdcontract) {
                                $query->where('contracts.id', 'LIKE', "%{$cdcontract}%");
                            })
                            ->when($branch != null, function ($query) use ($branch) {
                                $query->where('branches.name', 'LIKE', "%{$branch}%");
                            })
                            ->get();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                            ->join('branches', 'branches.id' , '=', 'contracts.branch_id')
                            ->when($name != null, function ($query) use ($name) {
                                $query->where('affiliates.first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%");
                            })
                            ->when($lastname != null, function ($query) use ($lastname) {
                                $query->where('affiliates.last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$lastname}%");
                            })
                            ->when($cellphone != null, function ($query) use ($cellphone) {
                                $query->where('contracts.cellphone', 'LIKE', "%{$cellphone}%");
                            })
                            ->when($domicile != null, function ($query) use ($domicile) {
                                $query->where('contracts.domicile', 'LIKE', "%{$domicile}%");
                            })
                            ->when($cdcontract != null, function ($query) use ($cdcontract) {
                                $query->where('contracts.id', 'LIKE', "%{$cdcontract}%");
                            })
                            ->when($branch1 != null, function ($query) use ($branch1) {
                                $query->where('branches.id', 'LIKE', "%{$branch1}%");
                            })
                            ->get();
        }
return $contracts->map(function ($contract) {
            return [
                'id' => $contract->id,
                'number' => $contract->full_number,
                'holder_last_name' => $contract->last_name,
                'holder_first_name' => $contract->first_name,
                'domicile' => $contract->domicile,
                'phone' => $contract->phone,
                'cellphone' => $contract->cellphone,
                'branch' => $contract->branch->name,
                'current_fee' => $contract->current_fee,
            ];
        })->toArray();
```

esta es la vista que me devuelve la consulta, como pueden ver no hay datos repetidos, sin embargo me aparece en la consola que si hay datos repetidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuales son los datos que vienen? porque el error parece de datos. y por favor, el error siempre como texto!

Comment: ahi lo agrego a los datos

Comment: ya agregue la consulta que realizo con el controller

Comment: Pone el error de vuelta como texto.. y que datos devuelve esa consulta? no hay id repetidos?

Comment: listo ya subi la consulta y puse de nuevo la advertencia

Comment: aca esta el error props.item.id.. ahi vienen datos duplicados.. deberia ir la clave de cada registro...

Comment: al hacer el dump para fijarme el arreglo por alguna razon me trae el campo id repetido

Comment: Entonces tu problema no es vue.. es el arreglo... fijate de cambiar tu pregunta hacia ese lado

Answer (score 1):

Le estás diciendo al componente que itere sobre un arreglo señalándole que la llave de cada elemento es el ID:

```
<contract-edit v-bind:id="props.item.id" @contractUpdated="onContractUpdated"></contract-edit>
```

De manera que si editas una fila, Vue sepa cuál es el elemento que se está referenciando en el array.

Sin embargo, como muestras en la imagen, hay dos filas con el mismo id `0002-3`. Cuando llames al método `onContractUpdated` qué fila querrás editar en realidad?

**PD** por la estructura de tu query, me da la impresión de que el árbol sería algo como

- branch 1

  - contract 1-1

    - affiliate 1-1-1
    - affiliate 1-1-2
  - contract 1-2

    - affiliate 1-2-1
    - affiliate 1-2-2
- branch 2

  - contract 2-1

    - affiliate 2-1-1
    - affiliate 2-1-2

De manera que el ID único viene del afiliado y no del contrato, dado que según la cláusula:

```
 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id'
```

Dos afiliados podrían tener el mismo contrato

Comment: perdon por demorar en responder, pero tienes razon me salia con id=1 en todos los registros, gracias, cambie la consulta y ahora si me trae todos los id como correnponde